# Fortune cookie game in Python

Tags: python, random

This is I'm sure a fairly rudimentary questions involving Python, but I've only recently started using the program. Here is the challenge:

"Write a program that simulates a fortune cookie. The program should display one of five unique fortunes, at random, each time it's run."

My approach was to assign five distinct variables their own individual fortunes:

```
fortune_1 = str("Good things come to those who wait.")
fortune_2 = str("Patience is a virtue.")
fortune_3 = str("The early bird gets the worm.")
fortune_4 = str("A wise man once said, everything in its own time and place.")
fortune_5 = str("Fortune cookies rarely share fortunes.")
```

What I am not clear on is how to generate the fortunes at random. Is there a way to utilize the random. module to pick one of the five predetermined fortunes uniquely each time? For example, could I set those five fortunes as numbers and then say something like:

```
user_fortune = random.randfortune(1,5)
```

? I hope this makes sense. As I am new to Python and posting in this forum it may take me some time to communicate more clearly.

Thanks!

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `str` like you are doing. `fortune_1 = "A string."` already assigns `fortune_1` as a string. The extra `str` you are using unnecessarily converts a string to a string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first instinct was to tell you to put your fortunes into a sequence of some kind (e.g., list, tuple).  Then, you just need to pick a random element.  I did the following at the Python prompt:

```
>>> import random
>>> help(random)
Help on module random:

NAME
    random - Random variable generators.

FILE
    /usr/lib/python2.7/random.py

MODULE DOCS
    http://docs.python.org/library/random

DESCRIPTION
        integers
        --------
               uniform within range

        sequences
        ---------
               **pick random element**
               pick random sample
               generate random permutation

        distributions on the real line:
```

Aha! "pick random element" sounds good.  So, I keep scrolling:

```
 |  **choice**(self, seq)
 |      Choose a random element from a non-empty sequence.
 |
```

Aha again!  I suppose I should have just known this, but it's good to know how to look this stuff up when you need it.

Possible solution (Python 2.7):

```
import random
fortunes = ["Good things come to those who wait.",
            "Patience is a virtue.",
            "The early bird gets the worm.",
            "A wise man once said, everything in its own time and place.",
            "Fortune cookies rarely share fortunes."]
print random.choice(fortunes)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the fortunes to a list and select a random item from the list using `choice`:

```
import random

fortunes = [fortune_1, fortune_2, fortune_3, fortune_4, fortune_5]
print random.choice(fortunes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much!

I also noticed that I could try the following:

```
import random

fortune = random.randint(1,5)

if fortune == 1:
    print("Good things come to those who wait.")
elif fortune == 2:
    print("Patience is a virtue.")
elif fortune == 3:
    print("The early bird gets the worm.")
elif fortune == 4:
    print("A wise man once said, everything in its own time and place.")
elif fortune == 5:
    print("Fortune cookies rarely share fortunes.")
```

Comment: the other solutions are much more "pythonic" - i.e. generally considered better.

Comment: This is the most obvious and least useful solution, and the one that beginners most often start with. The problem is that it does not scale. Are you going to write out 99 `elif` statements if you wind up with 100 random values to choose from? Every language supports arrays in these situation specifically so that you *don't* have to write out massive if/else statements like this one.

Answer (score 0):

imort random
fortune_cookie = random.choice([""Good things come to those who wait.",
"Patience is a virtue.",
"The early bird gets the worm.",
"A wise man once said, everything in its own time and place.",
"Fortune cookies rarely share fortunes."])
print(fortune_cookie)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).